# My Laptop became extremely slow and found error with hard disk

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery, hard-drive-failure, check-disk

I am using Dell Inspiron N5010 (windows 8). It was working fine, suddenly it became extremely slow. So I had restored my laptop to a previous Restore Point. After restoring I got this error message.

**"Windows detected a hard disk problem"**

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should replace the hdd

Comment: No i am having importatnt files in it. Is there any other way to fix this

Comment: There is no fixing your hdd

Answer (score 3):

**Do exactly what the error message is suggesting for you to do, sooner rather than later...**

The more you use the device the more chance of the HDD failing entirely and you losing the data permanently (or at great cost for a forensic recovery if you really need the data).

Not having a backup of your most important data is either very brave or very stupid.

Comment: I know the situation, and I know to do backup. All i am asking is a solution (if any) to fix the problem.

Comment: Backup the disk and put a new one in... I hope you have a recovery disk so you can re-install your OS (if not then you'll have to contact your laptop manufacturer to buy replacement disks - they're not cheap and may take a while to deliver). Trying to fix an already failing disk is a useless exercise as the disk will only deteriorate further to the point it will fail entirely.